# How do you leave roots in surd form in c#?

Tags: c#, algebra, sqrt

**Example a**: √12 =2√3

**Example b**: √16 = 4

I am trying to get both.

Whilst I can of course use `Math.Sqrt(4)` to achieve outcome **b**, I've no idea how to achieve **a**, or further how to get both to work simultaneously which is the goal. How do I achieve this type of simplification in C#?

I have tried several libraries including MathNet, Symbolics and NCalc with no success. 
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492855/simplify-square-roots-algebraically) may have solved it in c++, although I do not know for sure. My attempts at converting that solution to even see if it worked were very much a failure:

```
var outside_root = 1;
var inside_root = 800;
var d = 2;
while (d * d <= inside_root)
    if (inside_root % (d * d) == 0)  //# inside_root evenly divisible by d * d
    {
        inside_root = inside_root / (d * d);
        outside_root = (outside_root * d);
    }
while (d * d > inside_root) { 
d = (d + 1);}
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: @WashingtonA.Ramos I'm not sure how that is a useful response

Comment: Consider using a prime factoring algorithm. For example 12 would have 2, 2, 3. Sort the factors (so that the two 2s are next to each other). Then go through the list. Any pair of factors becomes an integer, the singletons that remain are roots

Comment: @Flydog57 sorry yes I made a typo, very long day, I think you get the idea I'm after surd form and whole numbers not decimals when rooting - googling around for prime factoring algorithms now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given C++ can be translated into C# without a lot of changes. Also a couple of modifications can be made to the original algorithm to reduce number of multiplications and increase overall performance:

```cs
    static (int, int) Sqrt2(int n)
    {
        int m = 1, d = 2;

        int dSquared;
        while ((dSquared = d * d) <= n)
        {
            while ((n % dSquared) == 0)
            {
                n /= dSquared;
                m *= d;
            }
            d++;
        }

        return (m, n);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Sqrt2(12)); // prints (2, 3)
        Console.WriteLine(Sqrt2(16)); // prints (4, 1)
        Console.WriteLine(Sqrt2(13)); // prints (1, 13)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be one of the solution

I think this is efficient. I used it in my calculator app

I did that using java. Hope this will help

```
static void surd_form(long a) {
long i = 2;
long sq = 1;
long k = 4;
long p = 1;
while (k <= a) {
    if (a % i == 0) {
        if (a % k == 0) {
            a /= k;
            sq *= i;
        } else {
            a /= i;
            p *= i;
        }
    } else {
        i += 1;
    }
    k = i * i;
}
System.out.println(sq + "" + "√" + (a * p));
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).